# turn off gps without turning off location services in ios7

Tags: ios7, gps

Is it possible to disable GPS without disabling location services?

What I would like to do is essentially dumb-down location accuracy but removing gps function from my phone.

Im aware that I may not have accurate location - and im ok with that.

I just want to know if gps can be disabled and only use cell tower triangulation to determine my (approximate) location.

Thank you.

Igor

Comment: Its related to testing GPS Apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is related to programming in the case of testing:
You cannot disable GPS with a iPhone/iPad setting while keeping cell tower location services,
but:
GPS is easily shielded by some metal foil, while GSM is very dificult to shield.
Try wrapping your phone into aluminium foil, you get in every super market.

That should shield GPS, while Cell Tower Triangulation still works.

That way I tested my Gps App.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the GPS directly. But you can specify the desired accuracy of the location, so you can specify a very large distance as acceptable, and stop updating location when you get it.

Also if you use [region monitoring](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html), the GPS is much less impacted (if at all), because it uses cell towers primarily.